# glBindTexture gives GL_INVALID_ENUM when using GL_TEXTURE_2D

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I'm writing a C++/OpenGL v3.1 program with glsl version 1.20. I'm trying to make a call to glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture_id_) where the m_texture_id_ obviously is a GLuint containing the texture ID. Running std::runtime_error, this always gives me GL_INVALID_ENUM, although (at least to me) the call to glBindTexture seems to be correct. Here's some code:

```
void Texture::Load(const std::string &filename) {
  // Load only if we havent done so already
  if(m_texture_id_ == 0) {
    // skip
    // Insert texture creation here
    // Use gli::createTexture2D to load and create texture name and bind it
    m_texture_id_ = gli::createTexture2D(filename); 
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture_id_);  // <----- Error occurs here!!!
    // Set wrapping to repeat in both S and T directions
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    // Set linear interpolation for magnification and linear-mipmap-linear for minification
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // Construct mipmaps
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE);
    // unskip
  }
}
```

Has anyone encountered this error before? Which steps should I take to fix this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the`std::runtime_error` mechanism. Just to be sure, can you put a `glGetError()` call immediately before `glBindTexture()`? I'm not convinced that the error is really from that call.

Comment: @RetoKoradi You're right, the error isn't from that call, it's from gli's createTexture2D function. It makes a call to glCompressedTexImage2D which seems to throw the GL_INVALID_ENUM error. The only enum gli uses is GL_TEXTURE_2d. I will update the OP.

Comment: It's probably trying to use a compressed texture format that is not supported on your platform.